# Create a PDF document for every Customer in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, pdf, crystal-reports

I need to create a PDF file for each customer that comes as result of a select from SQL query.

For example for "Customer 1" all the information of this customer should go to a file named "Customer1.pdf". Then "Customer 2" with all the information in "Customer2.pdf" and so on until the last customer from the SQL query.

The code works, the problem is the loop to create each document for every customer: it only creates *one* document with all the information.

Example of my VB.net code:

```
Dim customer_SQL As String

Using connObj As New SqlConnection(sql conection)
    Using cmdObj As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select Distinct(customer_ID) from my table  Where custmerid is not null", connObj)
        connObj.Open()
        Using readerObj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdObj.ExecuteReader
            ' This will loop through all returned records '
            While readerObj.Read
                Customer_SQL = readerObj("Customer_ID").ToString
                ' To see if it return the value I want
                'MessageBox.Show(Customer_SQL.ToString)

                Try
                    Dim CrExp As ExportOptions
                    Dim CrDiskFileDest As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()
                    Dim crFormatTypeopt As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
                    For Li_count As Integer = 0 To Customer_SQL
                        CrDiskFileDest.DiskFileName = "C:\Report" & Customer_SQL.ToString & ".pdf"
                        CrExp = cryRpt.ExportOptions
                        With CrExp
                            .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
                            .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
                            .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDest
                            .FormatOptions = crFormatTypeopt

                        End With
                        cryRpt.Export()
                    Next
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                End Try
            End While
        End Using
        connObj.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks Tim...for correct it

Comment: If you correct the problems shown by using [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) you might have a working program. Also, is "custmerid" in the SQL query the correct spelling?

Comment: I would not normally change the substance of code when editing its format, but the line `Using cmdObj As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select Distinct(customer_ID) from my table  Where custmerid is not null, connObj)` was missing an essential closing double-quote. I assume that was a transcription error.

Comment: No , its happens when I copy the the code into here, maybe the  Editor corrector did something. But the Code works,  when I run it work, but create all information for each customer :(

Comment: I have never used crystal report, but that ineer loop `For Li_count As Integer = 0 To Customer_SQL` looks unecessary for me.. Try removing it

Comment: I know nothing about Crystal Reports, but it seems to me that you need to tell `cryRpt` each value of `Customer_SQL`.

Comment: The Crystal part works OK. If I take out the For Next don`t do anything its go into a loop whit out end

Answer (score 0):

```
 Using connObj As New SqlConnection(sql conection)
    Using cmdObj As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select Distinct(customer_ID) from my table  Where custmerid is not null, connObj)
            connObj.Open()
            Using readerObj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdObj.ExecuteReader
                'This will loop through all returned records 
                While readerObj.Read
                    Customer_SQL = readerObj("Customer_ID").ToString
                    ' To see if it return the value I want
                    'MessageBox.Show(Customer_SQL.ToString)

                    Try
                        Dim CrExp As ExportOptions
                        Dim CrDiskFileDest As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()
                        Dim crFormatTypeopt As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
                        For Li_count As Integer = 0 To Customer_SQL

                            CrDiskFileDest.DiskFileName = "C:\Report" & Li_count & ".pdf"

                            CrExp = cryRpt.ExportOptions
                            With CrExp
                                .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
                                .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
                                .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDest
                                .FormatOptions = crFormatTypeopt

                            End With
                            cryRpt.Export()
                        Next
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                    End Try
                End While
            End Using
            connObj.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

I think the error is on 16th line

Comment: Hello Ricardo , I change it  and create the same document over and over. I want a different Document for every different  customer

Comment: Did you try my solution?
`CrDiskFileDest.DiskFileName = "C:\Report" & Li_count & ".pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with this , Thanks all for help me by :
Also if somebody need to burst a PDF file or any file from Visual Studio using Crystal Report.. This is the Firmula

```
Dim Customer_id As String
        Using connObj As New SqlConnection("SQL conection")
            Using cmdObj As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select Distinct(Customer_ID) from Customer_DIM", connObj)
                connObj.Open()
                Using readerObj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdObj.ExecuteReader
                    'This will loop through all returned records 
                    While readerObj.Read
                        Customer_id = readerObj("Customer_ID").ToString
                        'Parameters
                        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("Prompts_Customer_id", Customer_id)

                        Dim List As New List(Of String) From {Customer_id}

                        'handle returned value before next loop here

                        Try
                            Dim CrExp As ExportOptions
                            Dim CrDiskFileDest As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()
                            Dim crFormatTypeopt As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
                            For Each Customer_id In List
                                CrDiskFileDest.DiskFileName = "C:\Report\R" & Customer_id & ".pdf"
                                CrExp = cryRpt.ExportOptions
                                With CrExp
                                    .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
                                    .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
                                    .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDest
                                    .FormatOptions = crFormatTypeopt

                                End With
                                cryRpt.Export()
                            Next Customer_id
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                        End Try
                    End While
                End Using
                connObj.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```